# How can i if dont send image implement default image on my user?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, multipartform-data, multer

**Hi** *everyone My users have profile picture but its not required,I dont want. So I need if user send me image while register or updated i take this picture and save, so i can this. My problem if user dont send me image i cant give default image*

**Its my controller code :**

```
//User Register Controller
const register = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const {
            name,
            surname,
            username,
            phoneNumber,
            email,
            password,
            gender,
            profilPicture,
            birtDate,
        } = req.body;
        bcrypt.hash(password, 8, async (err, hash) => {
            try {
                const user = new User({
                    name,
                    surname,
                    username,
                    phoneNumber,
                    email,
                    password: hash,
                    gender,
                    profilPicture: 'http://localhost:4000/' + req.file.path || 'http://localhost:4000/public/images/profilePictures/defaultProfilePicture.png',
                    birtDate,
                });
                const createdUser = await user.save();
                const token = await createToken(createdUser);
                res.status(200).json({ token });
            } catch (err) {
                res.json(err);
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({ message: error.message });
    }
};
```

**It's my middleware multer :**

```
const multer = require('multer');
const stor = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:function(req,file,cb) {
        cb(null,'./public/images/profilePictures')
    },
    filename:function(req,file,cb){
        cb(null,'profilePicture-'+new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-')+file.originalname);
    }
})
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
        cb(null, true);
    } else {
        cb(null, false);
    }
};
const upload = multer({
    storage: stor,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5,
    },
    fileFilter: fileFilter,
});

module.exports = upload;
```

**My route :**

```
router.post('/register', upload.single('profilPicture'), userController.register);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do it is set a default within your model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    profilePicture: {
        type: String,
        default: 'defaultProfilePicture.png'
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Users", UserSchema)
```

This way if the user didnt upload a profile picture it would be set to defaultProfilePicture.png

You wouldnt need

```
profilPicture: 'http://localhost:4000/' + req.file.path || 'http://localhost:4000/public/images/profilePictures/defaultProfilePicture.png',
```

Just

```
profilPicture: 'req.file.path'
```

saving the full URL is never a good idea because you might choose to change it in the future like to remote file store or host your project then the URL will no longer be http://localhost:4000/. You'd ideally save the images unique name and extension.

Comment: I dont need just default picture , Sorry i cant tell my self enough, if i can send request without picture , throw error about req.bile.path is undefined

Comment: profilPicture: (req.file) ? req.file.path : 'public/images/profilePictures/defaultProfilePicture.png' if you're planning to host your project in the future saving localhost will cause you issues.

Answer (score 0):

just try like this :

```
profilPicture: (req.file) ? 'http://localhost:4000/' + req.file.path : 'http://localhost:4000/public/images/profilePictures/defaultProfilePicture.png';
```